# Google PubSub sync pull not respecting MaxOutStandingMessages

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using `Go` library. The service is deployed on kubernetes cluster and when I send flood of messages, it somehow ends up on one pod and other pod is just idle.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
  ctx := context.Background()

  subId := os.Getenv("MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID")

  log.Infof("Pulling messages from %s pubsub subscriber", subId)
  sub := client.Subscription(subId)
  cfg, err := sub.Config(ctx)

  sub.ReceiveSettings.Synchronous = true
  sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxExtension = cfg.AckDeadline
  sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = 1

      
  / Pull MaxOutstanding Messages
  // NOTE: Receive will spawn new goroutines for each incoming messages,
  // limited by MaxOutstandingMessages and MaxOutstandingBytes in ReceiveSettings
   
   err = sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {

       // Process the msg
       process_message( ....)

   })
   if err != nil {
       log.Errorf("subscriber got canceled: %v", err)
   }
```

I see I have like 20+ goroutines spawned on one pod and while other pod is doing nothing. I know numOfGoRoutines can't be really limited (it would have to be MaxOutstandingMessages) but still that's too many when the MaxOutstandingMessages is set to one.

Note: all the pods are using one subscription that I created on GCP console. I don't want to process ALL messages by ALL the subscribers. I want the messages to be distributed.

Comment: What's the rate at which you are publishing messages? Are you using the Go library for publishing as well, and if so could you paste the settings for that?

Comment: @AlexHong Thx for looking but looks like it is working fine as expected after the day I posted (i know i look foolish now). I was using a python script to publish message and I was publishing 20 message in one shot to see how it reacts. I am thinking to delete this question as it is working as expected

Comment: Not foolish at all. Glad it's working! If you have any more details on how you might've gotten it to work, might help other people in the future. Cheers!

Comment: roger that. I tried to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone coming here:

It started working for me the next day I posted here. I did lot of experiments with above code but now that I look at the working code I see only difference from above code is that there is  `sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxExtension = 0`. I can't tell for sure it wouldn't work with that settings.

This is what my code looks like:

```
  sub := client.Subscription(subId)
  cfg, err := sub.Config(ctx)

  sub.ReceiveSettings.Synchronous = true
  sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxExtension = 0
  sub.ReceiveSettings.MaxOutstandingMessages = 1 //pick whatever number you want

      
  / Pull MaxOutstanding Messages
  // NOTE: Receive will spawn new goroutines for each incoming messages,
  // limited by MaxOutstandingMessages and MaxOutstandingBytes in ReceiveSettings
   
   err = sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {

       // Process the msg
       process_message( ....)

   })
   if err != nil {
       log.Errorf("subscriber got canceled: %v", err)
   }
```

Something to note is that this doesn't require `for` loop to pull messages, when `ctx` passed to `Receive` gets canceled it exists otherwise it keeps on listening. I also want to point out that it is important to `Nack` message when your worker routine fails for a message so that `Receive` won't wait till `AckDeadline` of subscriber on that message.